# How to reject inputs that are non digit characters?

Tags: java, character, counter

My professor assigned to write a prime number "finder". Where the number you input will display if it's a prime or even number, then display the next prime number. He wants us to give an error message when the wrong input is keyed in. I figured the negative integer portion is simple, but I cannot figure out the character input. Or if the character is not a digit. How would i block non numeric inputs?

Also, the system is supposed to exit at three CONSECUTIVE erroneous inputs. How would I reset the counter? The way i have written the program, if the user makes two errors but the next ones are acceptable, then make another error. (thus not being consecutive.) the program closes.
This is my first programing course so I'm not to savvy in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, i have to use scanner, and the two methods.

```
/**
 *
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}



public static int nextPrime(int n) {
    n++;
    isPrime(n);
    while (isPrime(n) == false) {
        n++;
        isPrime(n);
    }
    int prime = n;
    return prime;
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int answer = 2;
    int counter = 1;

    boolean playAgain = false;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        //ask for input
        System.out.print("\nEnter the integer value-> ");

        //input answer
        int n = input.nextInt();

        {
           //decide is negative
            while ( n < 0){
                //count counter
                counter++;
                //give error message
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Input! Stike!");

              //ask for input
              System.out.print("\nEnter the integer value-> ");

                 //input answer
                 n = input.nextInt();


            //decide is character
           // if ( n != '.'){
                //count counter
               // counter++;

                //give error message
              //  System.out.println("\nInvalid Input! Strike!");
           // }

            //decide if count three errors
            if (counter == 3){

            //display three errors message
            System.out.println("Three Strikes! You're Out!");
            //close program
            System.exit(0);
        }
            }

        //decide if prime
        if (isPrime(n)) {

            //display prime answer
            System.out.println(n + " Is Prime");

            //decide if even
        } else {

            //display even answer
            System.out.println(n + " Is Even");

        }

        //counter input
        n++;

        //while input is false
        while (isPrime(n) == false) {
            n++;
        }


        //display next prime
        System.out.println(n + " Next prime");

        {

            //ask if you want to continue
            System.out.println("\nPlay Again?\n\nEnter 1)Yes or 2)No ");
            //input answer
            answer = in.nextInt();


            //if answer is 1)yes
            if (answer == 1) {
                playAgain = true;

                //display play again and next input
                System.out.println("\nPlay Again!");
            }
            //if answer is no
            if (answer == 2) {
                playAgain = false;
                System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
                //close program
                System.exit(0);
            }


        }

        }

    } while (playAgain != false);
}
```

}

Comment: I agree, simple research should give you the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SOQ5B
{

   public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

      for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
         if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
         }
      }

      return true;
   }


   public static int nextPrime(int n) {
      n++;
      isPrime(n);
      while (isPrime(n) == false) {
         n++;
         isPrime(n);
      }
      int prime = n;
      return prime;
   }


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

      int answer;
      int counter = 0;
      int n;

      boolean playAgain = true;
      boolean isNum;
      boolean isNum2;
      boolean continuePermitted = true;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      String s;

      do {
        //ask for input
         System.out.print("\nEnter the integer value-> ");

         s = input.nextLine();


         isNum = true;

         for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
         {

            if(!(s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9'))
            {

               isNum = false;

            }

         }

         if(isNum)
         {

            counter = 0;

            n = Integer.parseInt(s);

         //decide if prime
            if (isPrime(n)) {

            //display prime answer
               System.out.println(n + " Is Prime");

            //decide if even
            } 
            else {

            //display even answer
               System.out.println(n + " Is Even");

            }

         //counter input
            n++;

         //while input is false
            while (isPrime(n) == false) {
               n++;
            }


         //display next prime
            System.out.println(n + " Next prime");


            do
            {

               continuePermitted = true;

            //ask if you want to continue
               System.out.println("\nPlay Again?\n\nEnter 1)Yes or 2)No ");
            //input answer

               s = input.nextLine();

               isNum2 = true;

               for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
               {

                  if(!(s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9'))
                  {

                     isNum2 = false;

                  }

               }


               if(isNum2)
               {

                  answer = Integer.parseInt(s);

               //if answer is 1)yes
                  if (answer == 1) {
                     playAgain = true;

                  //display play again and next input
                     System.out.println("\nPlay Again!");
                  }
               //if answer is no
                  if (answer == 2) {
                     playAgain = false;
                     System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
                  //close program
                     System.exit(0);
                  }

               }

               else
               {

                  System.out.println("Incorrect response.");
                  continuePermitted = false;

                  //if answering the yes or no question incorrectly is part of the 3 strikes
                  //then uncomment the following lines of code

                  /*
                  counter++;
                  }

                  if(counter >= 3)
                  {

                  System.out.println("3 strikes you out");
                  System.exit(0);
                  */

               }
            }while(!continuePermitted);


         }

         else
         {

            System.out.print("\nIncorrect input. Number must be a positive integer.\n");
            counter++;

         }

         if(counter>=3)
         {

            System.out.println("3 strikes and you're out!");
            System.exit(0);

         }




      } while (playAgain != false);
   }
}
```

In the future, I recommend you research your questions on the internet before bringing the question here. There were several other places that could've easily answered your question.

Now as for your actual question, notice how I changed your code at the line that says s = input.nextLine()? What I did there is checked to see if each digit in the string was any number between and including 0-9. Not only was I able to check if they were all numbers, but I was also able to see if they were all positive too as you would have to put a - in order for it to be negative. Along with that, you also have a boolean that only works when the input is a positive number. If not, it checks 3 times to make sure your program doesn't mess up. Furthermore, I even commented out another section that allows the 3 strikes to include if answering the yes no question counts as a strike. If there any other questions, just ask and I will edit my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your patience and assistance. I've spent hours online searching for an answer, and I'm sure I stumbled on one. Although yours explained the steps, well enough for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take input using Scanner class with

```
int n = input.nextInt();
```

If you enter a character in place of number here you will get **java.util.InputMismatchException**

What you can do is something like

```
try {
    int n = input.nextInt();    
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    //handle the error scenario where the input is a character
    System.out.println("Enter Valid Input");
}
```